# Ionic 3, iOS, iPhone X, crashes and reloads when pushing a page with navCtrl

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, ionic3, iphone-x

I'm using Ionic 3, and testing on my iPhone X (real device). All I'm doing is pushing a new Page onto the Stack (the first page in the stack), with the following code:

```
  pushNewPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(newPageDetails); 
  }
```

I'm getting the following error in Xcode:

```
[ProcessSuspension]  0x1d7e70580 - ProcessAssertion() Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 0
```

The App then simply reloads completely and continues to work fine, but never actually pushed the new page that I need!

Comment: What is `newPageDetails`? Is it `import { newPageDetails } from '../some-page'`?

Comment: Try to do this : this.navCtrl.push('newPageDetails');

Comment: Yes, it’s an imported page. The problem is memory. For some reason iPhone X crashes when too much memory is allocated. With iPhone 6, 7, and 7 plus, all works fine and it doesn’t crash, but the brand new iPhone X crashes.